# Editor on action-tmate on GitHub Action Runner

Tags: windows, github-actions

I'm debugging a workflow with [mxschmitt/action-tmate](https://github.com/mxschmitt/action-tmate) on Windows runner.
How can I edit a file on tmate?

Workflow file is like below.

```yaml
on:
  push:
    branches: ['*']
jobs:
  windows:
    runs-on: windows-2022
    defaults:
      run:
        shell: bash
    steps:
      - uses: mxschmitt/action-tmate@v3
```

When I run `vim` or `vi`, it says the input and the output are not terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are connected through [tmate](https://tmate.io/), which requires a terminal-based editor, you can try and [install Nano](https://superuser.com/a/1554299/141): it works well in various terminal environments, and might avoid the "input and the output are not terminal" error.

This assumes [Chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org/) is installed.

```yaml
on:
  push:
    branches: ['*']
jobs:
  windows:
    runs-on: windows-2022
    defaults:
      run:
        shell: bash
    steps:
      - uses: mxschmitt/action-tmate@v3
      - name: Install Nano
        run: |
          choco install -y nano
```

Comment: Thank you, `nano` works. Actually `nano` has already been installed on the host.

Comment: @kamae Great! That should be a good workaround, then.